# Tensorflow neural network doesn’t learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I built a neural network for a university project. The goal is to find out if sensor data (temperature, humidity and light) can predict if the sunrise happened during a given time frame. So, it is a binary classification.
The problem is that the network does not learn. The accuracy converges towards about 0.8 and does not change after about 5 epochs. Same with the loss, which sits at about 0.4921 after a few epochs. I tried several things like changing the activation function or the number of hidden layers, but nothing worked.

I also created a dataset with an equal amount of  "sunrise = 1" and "sunrise = 0" data points. The accuracy ended up at exactly 0,5. Therefore I think that there is something wrong with the network setup itself.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
def build_network():
input = keras.Input(shape=(4,25), name="input")
hidden = layers.Dense(1000, activation="sigmoid", name="dense1")(input)
hidden = layers.Dense(1000, activation="sigmoid", name="dense2")(hidden)
hidden = layers.Flatten()(hidden)
hidden = layers.Dense(500, activation="sigmoid", name="dense3")(hidden)
hidden = layers.Dense(500, activation="sigmoid", name="dense4")(hidden)
hidden = layers.Dense(10, activation="sigmoid", name="dense5")(hidden)
output = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output")(hidden)
model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output, name="sunrise_model")
return model

 def train_model():
training_files = r'data/training'
test_files = r'data/test'

print('reding files...')
train_x, train_y = load_data(training_files)
test_x, test_y = load_data(test_files)

print("training network")

# compile model
model = build_network()
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

# Train / fit
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=100, epochs=200)

# evaluate
test_scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=2)
print("Test loss:", test_scores[0])
print("Test accuracy:", test_scores[1])
```

Here is the output: loss: 0.4921 - accuracy: 0.8225

Test loss: 0.4921109309196472,
Test accuracy: 0.8225

And here is an example of the data: https://hastebin.com/hazipagija.json

Comment: How did you initialise your parameters? It looks like all the parameters are zero, so the back propagation won't work.

Comment: I thought model.fit initialise it. So I think that is the problem. Thanks for the fast answer. I will initialise the parameters and then take a look if it'll work

Comment: Keras takes care of the parameter initialization, that is not the problem. I am more suspicious of using sigmoid activation in all hidden layers, that will produce vanishing gradients, why don't you use ReLU in the hidden layers?

Comment: I also used relu in the layers, but the problem is the same. I just tried out some activation function - also mixed sigmoid and relu

Answer (score 1):

I would use RELU instead of sigmoid as the activation function. What was the learning rate you used? Try a smaller learning rate. Actually I find I get the best results using a variable learning rate. The Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau makes this easy to do. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/) I also recommend that you use the Keras callback ModelCheckpoint to save the model with the lowest validation loss then use that model to make predictions on the test set. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/)I also think your model has to many parameters and will overfit. Add dropout layers to the model to help reduce this problem. I would try reducing the model complexity as a good alternative. Take out in of the layers with 1000 nodes and one of the layers with 500 nodes and see what results you get. I also prefer to use the Adamax optimizer. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adamax). Use the default values.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice! I'll try it. My learning rate is 0.001 as this is the default of the Adam optimizer. But I'll try it with the variable learning rate and the other things you mentioned